# Extracting info by matching two datasets in SAS

Tags: sas

I have two datasets. Both have a  common column- ID. I would like to check if ID from df1 lies in df2 and extract all such rows from df1. I'm doing this in SAS.

Answer (score 1):

It is easily done in one sql query.

```
proc sql;
   create table extract_from_df1 as
   select 
       *
   from
       df1
   where 
       id in (select id from df2)
   ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to do this. For example:

```
proc sql;
    create table compare as select distinct
        a.id as id1, b.id as id2
        from table1 as a
        left join table2 as b
        on a.id = b.id;
quit;
```

and then keep matches. Or you can try:

```
proc sql;
    delete from table2 where id2 in select distinct id1 from table1;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

data df1;
input id name $;
cards;
1 abc
2 cde
3 fgh
4 ijk
;
run;

data df2;
input id address $;
cards;
1 abc
2 cde
5 ggh
6 ihh
7 jjj
;
run;
data c;
merge df1(in=x) df2(in=y);
if x and y;
keep id name;
run;
proc print data=c;
run;

Comment: You are missing a BY statement for the merge.